# How to silence "Did you mean ...?" suggestions of sorbet errors?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I am starting to introduce [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org/) to a code base. Every time I switch a file from `typed: false` to `typed: true`, there are tons of errors about methods of my classes where I haven't added RBI files or sigs yet. That's fine and expected.

But these errors are drowned in even more suggestions of supposed typos of similarly named methods from the standard library and gems. I guess this feature is very handy later on, but at this early stage I would like to turn it off. How?

(I've looked in `srb tc --help` of version 0.4.4239, without success.)

Comment: My workaround is `srb tc |& grep '^[^[:space:]]'`

Comment: Have you tried [Disabling did_you_mean](https://github.com/yuki24/did_you_mean#disabling-did_you_mean)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but `RUBYOPT='--disable-did_you_mean' srb tc` did not help. That part is implemented in Rust I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported yet. Good idea!

If someone wants to implement it, I'd be onboard with an advanced command line flag and/or reusing the environment variable that the runtime inspects.

Comment: +1, this is a great idea. In particular, given that "Did you mean" suggestions are very computationally intensive and, if there are many of them, Sorbet takes substantially longer to run.